# how to have dom adjust for new jquery behavior

Tags: jquery

I thought this should work but it's not. I have a "follow" button which can be either of the following states:

```
<div class='toggls_user_follow' data-user-id='3'>follow</div>

<div class='toggls_user_follow following' data-user-id='3'>following</div>
```

with the following jquery for when a user mouseovers:

```
$('.toggle_user_follow.following').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).html('unfollow');
   $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
});

// in state of following, ajax call has been made and following has been removed

$that.removeClass('following');
$that.html('follow');
```

However, the dom element still has the initial behavior.

How would I adjust the jquery behavior so that it adopts the new selector?

#### EDIT #1

So, the gist of the problem is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4rgr4ot/3/

We remove the .following when we mouse out but the jquery even is still attached.

#### EDIT #2

updated the fiddle link to http://jsfiddle.net/k4rgr4ot/3/

basically, .following is removed but the behavior of the alert still exists. It shouldn't alert since the .following is gone.

#### EDIT #3

cool, so something like this works:

```
  $('body').on('mouseover','.toggle_user_follow.following',function(){
     $(this).html('unfollow');
     $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
  });

  $('body').on('mouseout','.toggle_user_follow.following',function(){
     $(this).html('following');
     $(this).removeClass('btn-danger');
  });
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Please explain expected behavior in words. Between fragmented description and disjointed code it's not clear exactly what you want. You can check class within event handler if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

**1.)** Remove the original event handler with `.off()` and rebind the appropriate handler

**2.)** (the best option) Use event [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than direct binding

Comment: right, thx now I remember. I have added a reasonable sol'n in EDIT #3 above if anyone stumbles across this.